# Transfer multiple files in a directory on a local server to different directories on remote server in Python

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko

There are some files inside a directory on an Informatica Server. I need to transfer these files onto another server based on their file names into different directories.

Say there are 2 files, `a.dat_1` and `b.dat_2` inside a directory called `low` on the Informatica server.

I need to transfer this `low` directory onto another server where the file `a.dat_1` goes to a directory say, `local` and `b.dat_2` goes to another directory called `local2`. This needs to be done in Python.

I have used Paramiko to do simple transfers but not directories. And not in separate directories like local and local2.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `tar` archive out of your directory. For this use shell command

```
tar -cvf archive_name.tar directory_name
```

then transfer this archive to another machine and `untar` it there:

```
tar -xvf archive_name.tar
```

You could also uze gzip or other compressor on your tarred archive to make the transfer faster.

Answer (score 1):

Given this SO [Directory transfers on paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409502/directory-transfers-on-paramiko); you won't be able to copy a directory as a bulk operation.

If it were me, I'd create a temp folder and start by copying the source files into a directory structure compatible with your destination requirements. Then compress them as [yakxxx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1333325/yakxxx) suggests, send the compressed file over the wire with Paramiko SFTP and uncompress on the other end with Paramiko SSH.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that, the directories 'loacl' and 'local2' already exist on the second server. So if I make a temporary directory set up and send it over and then uncompress it won't I have a duplicate?

Comment: You won't have a duplicate directory. You may overwrite files in those directories. Which may or may not be a bad thing for you. You're biggest challenge at that point is coming up with an acceptable process of compression/decompression. Whereas, with your original approach, it seems to me that you'll have additional complexity to deal with. In my opinion its the difference between a process that works like this: "do this then this then this" and one that works like this: "do this and then if this do that else do other". The former is always more attractive to me than the latter.

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar for transferring files daily.  As yakxxx suggests, I zip my files then transfer.  Example of what I do (on Windows machines):

```
import zipfile
from glob import glob as gg

files = gg('path*.txt')
# open zip file (create it, or open if already exists)
zFile = zipfile.ZipFile('FileName.zip','w') 

# zip files on local machine
[zFile.write(r,r,zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) for r in files]
```

Alternately, if the zipfile already exists and you want to add new files.

```
zFile = zipfile.ZipFile('FileName.zip','a')

# List files already zipped.  
done = zipfile.ZipFile('FileName.zip','r').namelist()

# zip file into zip file.  
[zFile.write(r,r,zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) for r in files if r not in done]
```

Now push this zip file to your remote machine via paramiko.

## ---------------

EDIT

FYI, when writing to to zip files you need to be careful.  I wrote this assuming you are running within the directory that has the files you want to zip.  If you are not, you need to use:

```
import os
zFile.write(r,os.path.basename(r),zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```